# Is there way to launch coda environment from Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pytest

Is there any way to launch conda environment from Jenkins or activate conda from Jenkins in Linux, i have to execute unit test using pytest i need to use conda base environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate a python virtual environment using the `source` command.

If you run a python script from Jenkins like this:

```
sh "source /path/to/my_env/bin/activate && python3 YOUR_SCRIPT.py"
```

It should run YOUR_SCRIPT.py from the python virtual environment called "my_env".